# Setting up DNS server on Windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7, domain-name-system

I have Windows 7 x64 ultimate installed on my development machine. Recently i registered for DynDNS free service. What I would like to do is set up several first  level domains in my IIS and setup DNS server on my machine. Could you please provide with helpful information regarding installing and configuring DNS server on Windows 7

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think its possible to run the Microsoft DNS server service on Windows 7, you would need an actual server OS (like Server 2k8) for that.  However there may be some third party DNS servers apps that you can run - but I don't know of any.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [BIND](http://www.isc.org/software/bind) for Windows